# User can't save any changes on an SMB share

Tags: macos, permission, smb, active-directory

We run a mixed environment of Mac/Windows. Our Macs are on High Sierra and using Windows Server 16. This is issue is only happening to this domain user. Our permissions are very flat, everyone has access to everything.

We use SMB://filesharedrive to connect and use our AD credentials to verify.

I have a domain user who can't make changes to a file (doc, excel, txt, etc.) on our company drive hosted on Windows Server 16. They get a 
*<"Alert: Your changes could not be saved to "Filename" because of a sharing violation. Try saving to a different file.>*

$UserA = problem user
$UserB = another random user, sometimes even me.

Both are domain users

Things I have tried and have figured out

- If $UserA creates a file, make changes and save on said file, no error
- If $UserB creates a file, make changes and save on said file, no error
- If $UserB makes a change to that file $UserA created, $UserA receives error
- If $UserA duplicates file and saves changes on duplicate file, no error
- If $UserB makes a change to duplicate file, $UserA receives error
- If $UserA uses a Windows Machine to save changes, no error
- If $UserA uses original Mac and save changes to the same file that worked on the windows machine, $UserA receives error.
- If $UserA signs into another Mac and tries to save changes $UserA receives error
- $UserA can delete, rename and move files whether created by $UserB but can only save changes as long as no other $UserB has saved any changes